# How to add inventory detalis to Assembly Build with suitescript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a process that takes a CSV file and import him to Netsuite.
It's a JSON object with assembly id, lot number, date, and quantity.

lotData is one line to insert: `{"assembly":"45","Lot Number":"2021 109 M 21 - 1","Expiry date":"12/05/2023","Quantity":"682"}`

```
function createInvDet(lotData) {
    try {
        var assemblyLotNum;
        
        for (var field in lotData) {

            if (field == 'assembly') {
                lotData[field] = getAssemblyId(lotData[field]) // getting the assembly build id

                assemblyLotNum = context.record.load({
                    type: record.Type.LOT_NUMBERED_ASSEMBLY_ITEM,
                    id: lotData[field],
                });
                
            }


        }
    } catch (error) {

    }
```

How can I get the inventory details sub-record and set the values there?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is in SuiteSCript 2.x and you've already loaded the 'N/record' Module, change

```
assemblyLotNum = context.record.load({
   type: record.Type.LOT_NUMBERED_ASSEMBLY_ITEM,
   id: lotData[field],
});
```

to:

```
assemblyLotNum = record.load({
   type: record.Type.LOT_NUMBERED_ASSEMBLY_ITEM,
   id: lotData[field],
});
```

there's no need for "context." before "record.load"

Comment: ok, still how can i insert the data to inventory details there?

Comment: To update the assembly item record?  Once it's loaded (using record.load), use record.setValue or record.setSublistValue.  I am not explicitly familiar with that record's field/set up but the ".set" methods in the Record Module can be referenced here: https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45152/kw/record%20module